# Mac use different Python version with virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I just installed Python 2.7.6.

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.6

$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

When I try to specify the Python version while creating a new virtualenv with

```
virtualenv -p /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7.6 test
```

I get:

```
The executable /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7.6 (from --python=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7.6) does not exist
```

If I simply use `virtualenv test` to create a new virtualenv I still get Python 2.7.5.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the value returned by `which`:

```
virtualenv -p /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python test
```

Python installations generally create executables and/or links to them with names like:

```
python
python2
python2.7
```

but not

```
python2.7.6
```

If you are concerned about confusion with the Apple-supplied system Python 2.7, don't be.  Its path is at `/usr/bin/python` or `/usr/bin/python2.7`.